# How to reload the page by emptying cache in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, shortcuts, browser-cache, webpage

I don't know what exactly it's called, by cache refresh I mean, refresh the page after clearing its cache. I don't want to clear the entire browser cache.

I can't seem to cache refresh my pages. In Firefox, I know it to be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Refresh.

In Chrome, I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Refresh, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Refresh, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Refresh but none of them work.

Comment: My version's 4.0.206.1
Tried it again after making a change to my source code (PHP). Refreshed fine in FF with Shift+F5. Change didn't show up Chrome after Ctrl+Refresh.

Comment: By "Ctrl+Refresh", do you mean actually clicking the refresh button? I don't know whether that works in Chrome; I'm nearly positive Ctrl+F5 works as expected, though.

Comment: Tried both with F5 and Refresh, Ctrl and Shift... no change. No proxy configured,

Comment: This bug [has been fixed](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1906) since the question was asked. This function did not exist and was added later. (Remember, Chrome is essentially beta software.)

Comment: Command-Shift-R works in Mac (OS X 10.6.7 and Chrome 17.0.963.56).

Comment: On a mac: hold CONTROL and click Chrome's reload button

Comment: Using SHIFT (not control) while clicking reload works for me on Mac

Comment: For me, an extension [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn) adds toolbar button. In options you can enable to `Reload active tab` after cleared cache. Also in extension manager you can assign keyboard shortcut to it to invoke it from keyboard. I use Ctrl+Del for this.

Comment: Keep a shortcut for chrome.exe -incognito or for IE, IExplorer.exe -private comes handy in task bar- these shortcuts helps to invoke private browsing which does not have knowledge of cache...

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+R works for me. Nevermind, tried all other combs with no luck.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Push <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to "Open Developer Tools" on Windows (On Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) then you can **right click** on the **refresh icon** and select **'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'**

[image: screenshot]

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633425/chrome-browser-reload-options-new-feature

The [documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179&topic=25799&rd=2) says:

- **For Windows and Linux:** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

  - (screenshot):  [image]
- **For Mac**: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>):

> Reloads your current page, ignoring cached content.

Although some have reported this works, others have said it does not work correctly

*Your other options are:*

1. **JavaScript Console**

   The JavaScript Console is available in two modes within Chrome DevTools: the primary Console tab, or as a split-view you can display while on another tab (such as Elements or Sources).

   To open the Console tab, do one of the following:

   Use the keyboard shortcut **Command** - **Option** - **J** (Mac) or **Control** -**Shift** -**J** (Windows/Linux).
   Select **View > Developer > JavaScript Console**.

   <kbd>F12</kbd> doesn't appear to be mentioned here but will open this console on Windows as well.

   [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview)

   [Using the  JavaScript Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console?hl=en)
2. **Incognito window**

   Another interesting option is to open a new incognito window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> On Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.). This window won't use any stored cookies, cached content, or DNS resolutions, so you can test stuff in it without slowing your normal browsing down by dumping the cache. This is what I almost always do instead of clearing the cache. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464
3. **Disable cache**

   Open Chrome Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>, Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). Click the settings icon (a gear in the bottom right corner). Check "Disable cache". Now when you browse with your Developer tools open caching is disabled.
4. **Click&Clean**

   Finally there is also the option of the [Click&Clean](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickclean/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod?hl=en-GB) extension

Comment: You don't need to open dev tools. 
Also F12 is for windows. On mac : ⌥⌘I  Source: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts

Comment: Not sure if it was the Click&Clean and Ctrl-F5 but it finally worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Came here looking for a _quick_ solution, sick of Ctrl+F5 not working, but this is very long-winded: it's quicker or me to do _hold_ Ctrl+F5 a second or two (rapidly reloading), which _does work_. Other than that, I don't even see the option you allude to in the first para, but you seem to miss the basic F12->Network->Right-Click->Clear Browser Cache. Granted this does do the _entire_ cache (not cookie etc., though).

Comment: Does the first sentence in my answer not work for you _Push F12 then you can right click on refresh and select 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'_ ?

Comment: Still says "(from cache)" for the root file. I can even shut down the server on localhost completely and the browser STILL won't return an error!!! This is extremely painful for me as a dev...

Comment: I'm pretty sure control-R used to work. Now control-F5 only seems to do it

Comment: _Disable cache_ is on the _Network_ tab of Developer Tools now.

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone said you do not need the dev tools open.  For me, you need them open and then this works great.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 65):

Another interesting option is to open a new incognito window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>). This window won't use any stored cookies, cached content, or dns resolutions, so you can test stuff in it without slowing your normal browsing down by dumping the cache. This is what I almost always do instead of clearing the cache.

Comment: +1 I find Chrome will cache file downloads. This is especially frustrating when I'm working on apache/nginx configs and I'm downloading index.php instead of viewing it.  The only way is the clear the entire cache, use incognito, or use Firefox.

Comment: argh, except *sometimes* it doesn't work. I just spent 15 minutes trying to figure out why my externally loaded SWF file wasn't accurate. Firefox showed it as being correct, no keystroke refresh combo in Incognito Chrome cleared the SWF from cache, nor did clearing the actual Chrome cache and refreshing the Incognito window. I had to close and re-open Incognito window completely for the cache to finally let go of the SWF. Was working fine for about an hour until this happened :/

Comment: Again 5 minutes later, this is not a reliable solution insofar as I can tell. Chrome v17.0.963.46 m

Comment: this will also disable extensions, which may go counter to some testing

Answer (score 19):

According to [documentation](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95743), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> should work.
Maybe you have a proxy configured on IE & chrome, which is caching your page?

Comment: If you really want to be sure you have to clear the cache using Tools options.

Comment: You need to clear the cache using Tools in order to flush the favicon from the cache; normal hard-reload doesn't do it.

Comment: Link in your answer no longer directs to the intended page.

Answer (score 9):

A [workaround](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1906) is hitting reload very quickly twice in a row.

Comment: Not in all cases it seems, I just had a page that didn't want to load because of earlier dns issues and Chrome simply refused to load it for about a minute... after that it worked again.

Comment: aside from more direct ways like disabling cache under network tabs or in preferences, I sometimes find that refreshing the page more than ten times has the clearing effect. Just repeatedly hit refresh 10-15 times

Answer (score 9):

I've had problems with Chrome refreshing in spite of using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.

What I've found works though pretty brutish is to hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for a few seconds so that the browser makes multiple attempts to refresh the Java cache and fails. Then the next time it successfully retrieve JS from the server.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this. I've been doing this myself.

Answer (score 9):

Chrome sucks for this.  Sometimes I can get <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to work but not always.  My solution for the moment is to use the ['Click & Clean'](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod?hl=en-gb) extension.  It's ugly but works every time so I'd recommend that for now.

Comment: For me, Ctrl+Shift+R **twice** works every time. I don't know why they made it so annoying.

Answer (score 8):

Open Chrome Developer Tools (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I or Menu/Tools/Developer Tools). Click the settings icon (a gear in the bottom right corner). Check "Disable cache". Now when you browse with your Developer tools open caching is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can right click, go `Inspect Element` under the `Resources` or `Application` (in newer versions) tab collapse `Cookies` right click on domain name and click `Clear`.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

it could simply be your keyboard settings, check if you have the functions keys enabled or disabled, with my logitech keybaord it is the FMode key, similar to NumLock!

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the Tools menu. (the wrench in the upper-right corner)
2. Select Options.
3. Click the Under the Hood tab.
4. Click Clear browsing data…
5. Check the boxes for the types of information you wish to delete.

   - Clear browsing history
   - Clear download history
   - Empty the cache
   - Delete cookies
   - Clear saved passwords

You can also choose the period of time you wish to delete cached information using the Clear data from this period dropdown menu.

6. Click Clear Browsing Data when ready.

Comment: Why would I delete my entire cache to test a single page?! I'd rather use Firefox.

Comment: Chrome is back in the picture as you can now hard reload - http://superuser.com/a/512833/92862

Answer (score 1):

**On Windows** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> for hard reload, and just <kbd>F5</kbd> for reload.

**On Mac** <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for hard reload and 
<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for reload.

*hard reload clears the stored cache for that page.*

> If you're interested in just testing stuff out, [go incognito](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). You can just close this window to clear all the temporary cache and history.

**On Windows**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

**On Mac**: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

## <**Google Chrome**>

Reload the page by emptying cache:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Reload the page by not emptying cache:

<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

## <**Firefox**>

Reload the page by emptying cache:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Reload the page by not emptying cache:

<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>