# How can I force Chrome to refresh a page, ignoring cached Flash files?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, swf

A [couple](https://superuser.com/questions/220179/cache-refresh-in-chrome) [other](https://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome) questions on superuser.com discuss the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in Chrome. In theory, that shortcut should cause Chrome to refresh the current page while ignoring cached content.

However, it does not appear to work for files downloaded by a Flash app, such as xml and images.

- Is there any way to get the files downloaded by Flash to refresh with a keyboard shortcut? Or will I be forever doomed to clicking "Tools -> Options -> Under the Hood -> Clear Browsing Data -> Empty the Cache"? (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> to bring up the same dialog)
- Are other people experiencing this issue? Should I [file a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)?

Thanks!

**Update:** Upon further investigation, I think I was mistaken initially. The .swf does indeed get refreshed, but some other items (xml & images) that are downloaded by the flash app do not. Manually clearing the browser cache is enough to force those other items to refresh, without having to mess with the [Flash cache manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html). A shift-refresh is enough to do the same job in Firefox without having to manually clear Firefox's cache. Could this be a Chrome browser bug?

Answer (score 10):

Try Ctrl-Shift-R (instead of Ctrl-r) to tell the browser to reload the page ignoring the cache.  You can also hold down the Shift key and click on the refresh button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more permanent solution, you could always tell Flash to stop caching content to begin with.

**Tools > Clear Browsing Data > Other Data Tab > Adobe Flash Player Storage Settings**

Once you are there, there are checkboxes that can toggle whether or not flash content is cached on your computer.

Also you can clear the cached data from here as well. Since Flash has its own data management tool, I doubt any browser would be able to enable shortcuts to clear this data.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the "flash cache" you describe that's the problem. Rather, it's the .swf file that is not being refreshed.

Comment: In the settings menu there are options for both 'flash cache' and the third party cache.

Comment: Are you saying that the "Adobe Flash Player Storage Settings" on [this page](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html) is what controls caching of .swf files? I don't believe that's the case, since emptying my browser cache via "Clear Browsing Data" causes my .swf to refresh.

Comment: Ok, I think I was mistaken about the .swf not refreshing. Rather, it's files that the .swf downloads that fail to refresh. Still, a regular browser cache clear is enough to get the files to refresh without having to mess with the "Adobe Flash Player Storage Settings".