# Chrome: lost multi-function reload button after update

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

Yesterday, I briefly discovered that holding the click on my Chrome's reload button opened a dropdown. It had:

- reload (ctrl+r)
- hard reload (shift ctrl +r)
- clear cache and reload

.

A few seconds later my office mate said his Chrome needed updating and checking mine I saw that it did too.

Unfortunately, after updating the awesome extended multi-function features of the reload button are no longer there.

Has anyone else discovered the multi-function relaod button or still have it or know how to get it back? And it wasn't an extension or a plug-in, none of those changed or were updated.

Any help clearing up my mystery is appreciated.

Comment: Also answered here... http://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome/512833#512833

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This reload menu only shows up if you have a Developer Tools window open (accessed via `Tools | Developer tools`).