# Javascript being cached in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force-refreshing only JavaScript files in Firefox and Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/36106/force-refreshing-only-javascript-files-in-firefox-and-chrome)

My javascript files appear to being cached in chrome. I am doing a lot of web development and it is getting very frustrating because the logic behind just isn't updating and I don't want to completely clear my cache or anything.

Is there any way to disable this? Or make sure that I am getting the most current js files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer... you need to go developer tools, settings (gear icon) and then disable cache.